# storage size of 'p' isn't known (sys/procfs.h struct psinfo p) error on Solaris

Tags: c, solaris, ps

I'm getting this error when trying to compile this simple program. The psinfo struct is in procfs.h. It's erroring on the definition line. Why would it not know the size of psinfo?

```
#include <sys/procfs.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        struct psinfo p;
}


$ /usr/sfw/bin/gcc little.c 
little.c: In function `main':
little.c:4: error: storage size of 'p' isn't known
```

Comment: I'm trying to get just the process name from the psinfo struct. This is basically how minimal gnu ps does it.

Comment: huh, if I try to define garbage, it get the same result "struct nothing_at_all g;" error: storage size of 'g' isn't known

Comment: Adding "#define _STRUCTURED_PROC 1" to the header fixed the problem. I took that from gnu minimal ps header. Weird?

Comment: I've removed the original (longer) example.

Comment: Which version of Solaris?

Comment: I noticed this in Solaris 11.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including `sys/procfs.h` was done by older code using the ioctl-based proc interface. Not to break these programs, the `psinfo` structure is currently kept undefined by default.

As you want to use the new interface, the simpler way to overcome this issue is to use this include statement:

```
#include <procfs.h>
```

which is documented in `/usr/include/sys/procfs.h`:

```
/*
 * This definition is temporary.  Structured proc is the preferred API,
 * and the older ioctl-based interface will be removed in a future version
 * of Solaris.  Until then, by default, including <sys/procfs.h> will
 * provide the older ioctl-based /proc definitions.  To get the structured
 * /proc definitions, either include <procfs.h> or define _STRUCTURED_PROC
 * to be 1 before including <sys/procfs.h>.
 */
```

Of course, predefining `_STRUCTURED_PROC` to `1` like documented too will also work as you experienced.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't notice that comment in the header file.

Answer (score 3):

Adding "#define _STRUCTURED_PROC 1" to the header fixed the problem. It needs to be defined before including sys/procfs.h.

The problem is that procfs.h sources sys/old_procfs.h unless _STRUCTURED_PROC does not equal 0 (apparently the default).

```
#if !defined(_KERNEL) && _STRUCTURED_PROC == 0
#include <sys/old_procfs.h>
#else   /* !defined(_KERNEL) && _STRUCTURED_PROC == 0 */
.....
#endif
```

Comment: http://www.unix.com/programming/70059-compiler-cant-find-pstatus_t-even-procfs-h-inlcuded.html

Answer (score 1):

You've allocated `p` on the stack. You should not be freeing it. Only `free()` that which you `malloc()`ed (or `calloc()`ed, or etc.).

Comment: Oh, duh. Thanks. That's not what caused that first error, but just ran into a segfault because of that unintended free().

Answer (score 1):

That indicates that the compiler needs to know what a `struct psinfo` is.

You need to include the header where the structure is defined. I don't have Solaris but, for example, this guy http://ivbel.blogspot.ca/2011/12/how-to-get-process-full-name.html also includes `procfs.h` before.

Comment: I had procfs.h defined, but it needed "#define _STRUCTURED_PROC 1" for some reason. I'm not sure what that is for.

Comment: @David note that `#include <sys/procfs.h>` is not necessarily the same thing as `#include <procfs.h>`

Comment: @David, Luis gave you the correct way to do it. It is quite unfair to vote his answer down.

Comment: @jlliagre I didn't down vote it, someone else did. I'll try Luis solution then.